# Discard all non-staged changes without committing?

Tags: git

Is there a simple way to discard all the changes that have not been staged without first committing the latter?

E.g., suppose that `A` is a tracked file, as in

```
% git init -q
% echo "state 1" > A
% git add A && git commit -q -m 'initial commit'
% cat A
state 1
```

Next one modifies `A`, and stages it:

```
% echo "state 2" > A
% git add A
% cat A
state 2
```

Finally, one modifies `A` a third time, but this time `A` remains unstaged:

```
% echo "state 3" > A
% cat A
state 3
```

How can one revert `A` to its *staged* state, namely **state 2**.

EDIT: I've changed the code sequence a little, hopefully it is now clearer.  I also posted a solution that occurred to me after I posted the question.  This solution strikes me as roundabout (there has to be something more direct), but at least it shows clearly the state where I want `A` to end up, both in the working directory and in the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this has been your workflow:

1. You committed a file
2. You made some changes and staged it
3. You made some more changes, but you want to revert to the version with the staged changes in step 2.

You just need to run `git checkout -- A`. This will get rid of any unstaged changes but will preserve the changes at the end of step 2.

Look at this example workflow which will clear things up:

Contents of A is just `version1`

```
$ echo "version1" > A
```

Commit the change
    $ git add A && git commit -q -m 'initial commit'

```
$ git log
commit 4fd90642df048ca4beeb29c65c5f7a436e83055a
Author: Tuxdude <foo@bar>
Date:   Fri Mar 8 16:28:36 2013 -0800

    initial commit
```

Contents of A is now `version2`

```
$ echo "version2" > A

$ cat A
version2
```

Stage the file changes

```
$ git add A
```

Check the current git status

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   A
#
```

Make some more changes to `A`

```
$ echo "version3" > A

$ cat A
version3
```

Now you decide, that you want to get rid of the local unstaged changes in `A. You just need to checkout the file from git's cache i.e the staging area.

```
$ git checkout -- A

$ cat A
version2
```

You can run `git status` once again and it will let you know about the staged changes.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   A
#
```

Comment: Sorry, but the workflow you posted does not reflect the one I asked about.  In my question `A` goes through 3 different states: the first one has been committed; the second one has been staged; the third one is the one in the current directory.  I want to recover the second one (so that it's not only staged, in the index, but also in the working directory).  After I posted the question, I thought of a solution, which I posted.  The solution is ugly, but at least it shows clearly what I was trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: @kjo - Your question is unclear to me - at least from the initial question you've posted. You have a file `A` which has been first committed, and then you have it staged and you have some unstaged changes which have not been committed is it ? And you want to recover to the version of the file at step 2 - where you had merely staged but not committed ? Can you confirm this ? I can update the example.

Comment: sorry for the confusion; I've edited the original to make it clearer, I hope.

Comment: @kjo - I've updated the answer as well to reflect this case :)

Comment: that was it.  I'd never realized that `checkout` pulled from the index; I always thought it pulled from `HEAD`.  The answer to this question turned out to be more instructive (to me anyway) than I'd realized.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do

```
git checkout -- .
```

If you want to revert a single file, you do

```
git checkout -- myfile
```

If the file has already been added, you have to un-stage it by doing

```
git reset HEAD myfile
```

Comment: This is correct, except for the third code snippet, which doesn't do what OP wants because OP wants to preserve the staged value and only remove the unstaged changes.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a possible answer to my question.  It's not particularly elegant, and I can't tell if it has any potential pitfalls, but at the very least it shows clearly the state where I want `A` to end up.  Hopefully someone will know a less roundabout route.

After the sequence given in the original question, do:

```
% git stash -q -k
% git stash drop -q
% cat A
state 2
```